# Rails loop: Show and hide element by id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm looping through the categories and subcategories with following code"

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li onclick="showHide()"> <%= category.name %>
      <% unless category.children.empty? %>
        <ul id="categories" style="display:none;">
          <% category.children.each do |subcategory| %>
            <li><%=  link_to "#{subcategory.name}", search_path(:search => subcategory.id) %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
     <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And I want to click on each category and then the subcategories will appear:

```
function showHide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("categories");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

But for some reason when I click on whatever category the first one opens and not the specific one I'm clicking on. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is scoping: you're not providing a context to `document.getElementById("categories");`, meaning it just selects the first element on the page with the `id` 'categories'.

While we're here, `id` should be unique to a page, so you're better switching anything rendered multiple times to use `class`.

To use the scope to the click event you can pass the `event` to the function, which we can use to find which `li` it is toggling.

So in your html:

```
<li onclick="showHide(event)">
```

And your function:

```
function showHide(e) {
    var parentCategory = e.currentTarget
    var categoryList = parentCategory.querySelector(".categories"); // << assuming you switch to using classes
    if(!categoryList) { return }
    if (categoryList.style.display === "none") {
        categoryList.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        categoryList.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

That way, you're looking for the categories within the clicked `li`, and you should see this toggle as expected.

You can also slim this down a little using a ternary if you're using es6:

```
function showHide(e) {
    let categoryList = e.currentTarget.querySelector(".categories");
    if(!categoryList) { return }

    categoryList.style.display = categoryList.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none"
}
```

Let me know how you get on, of if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SRack ... I'm getting the following error inside the browser console for both the codes you provided: `TypeError: this.querySelector is not a function. (In 'this.querySelector(".categories")', 'this.querySelector' is undefined)`

Comment: Apologies, I jotted this down a bit too quickly @Dev - I've updated (and, crucially, tested) now. Try the above and see if that works for you.

Comment: unfortunately it's still giving me an error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'categoryList.style')`

Comment: Did you switch `<ul id="categories" style="display:none;">` to `<ul class="categories" style="display:none;">` @Dev? Also, it'll need a guard where the categories list isn't rendered - 2 secs and that'll be in my answer.

Comment: Ok I got it to work @SRack I just changed to this : `("#categories");`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :))) edit your answer so I can upvote and accept it!

Comment: Thanks @SRack :)))